# How Previous Function passes its result to callback

Tags: javascript, callback

I'm trying to understand how a callback works in this case.

For example given this code:

```
var images = jQuery.map((1234567 + '').split(''), function(n) {
  return '<img src="' + n + '.png" />'
})
```

an anonymous function is passed in as the callback but how does 'n' magically get populated after each split??  How does it get passed into the n param?  I mean I wouldn't assume that split would inject its value into n..how does it even know to do that?

Lets take another example but this time, we're ***explicitly*** passing the param to the callback function

```
function randomGenerator(min, max, callback)
{
   var myNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
   setTimeout(function() { callback(myNumber); }, 500);
}
```

this is pretty straight forward, it's obvious how myNumber is being wired up (passed in explicitely) to callback();

The question is how is it ***implicitly*** doing that in my first example?  I mean can I assume map() has a hell of a lot more going on under the hood than I know?  Maybe I would have to dive into the implementation of Map() in the jQuery library I guess...or is there some general common knowledge around how implicit assignment works in JS?

Comment: my question still isn't really being answered.  I'm wondering how JS is doing this under the hood.  How in the map function JS is passing the number to the callback's param.  I mean it can't be magic, but how is it doing this at a very low level?  I don't just take things at face value for this one so that's why I'm trying to figure out deeper how it's working in JS.  And I already understand that I'm sending in a callback function, I said that.  I just don't get how magically it's wiring up number to n (I guess in very low level JS)

Comment: I mean could I create my own function that takes a callback where the callback has a param and somehow my initial function magically maps something to that callback's param?  I don't get how

Comment: I'm not trying to understand the map function's definition at a top level, I wanna know how JS is working under the hood to make this param injection happen!

Comment: I updated and added more to my original post, please read again, hopefully this helps you understand what I'm trying to get to

Comment: It's not implicit - it's the definition of the way `.map()` works. How does it work internally? Well, how does *any* function call work? The runtime has access to the array, and it can invoke functions. Passing parameters is an intrinsic part of calling functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have specified the anonymous function with a signature taking a parameter "n".
Internally the map function calls the anonymous one supplying a concrete object for parameter "n". If u remove the parameter it wont't work

Answer (score 3):

That's what the `.map()` function does. The `.split()` call just builds the array over which `.map()` will iterate.

The function passed to `.map()` is called once for each element in the array (the first argument). Each call is made with three parameters: the value of the element in the array; the *index* of the element, and the array itself. Your anonymous function just has one argument (which is common), so that'll be the element value.

Answer (score 0):

the specified map function gets called for every element in the array. A string is just an array of characters.

Answer (score 0):

Functions are objects like any other in JavaScript. You can pass them as arguments to other functions, then the other function can do whatever it likes with it.

```js
function do_something_with_two_numbers(something, num1, num2) {
    return something(num1, num2); 
}

function add(a,b) { return a + b };
function subtract(a,b) { return a - b };

alert(do_something_with_two_numbers(add, 2, 1));
alert(do_something_with_two_numbers(subtract, 2, 1));
```

[MDN has a polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) that serves as a complete example of `map`:

```
// Production steps of ECMA-262, Edition 5, 15.4.4.19
// Reference: http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.4.19
if (!Array.prototype.map) {

  Array.prototype.map = function(callback, thisArg) {

    var T, A, k;

    if (this == null) {
      throw new TypeError(' this is null or not defined');
    }

    // 1. Let O be the result of calling ToObject passing the |this| 
    //    value as the argument.
    var O = Object(this);

    // 2. Let lenValue be the result of calling the Get internal 
    //    method of O with the argument "length".
    // 3. Let len be ToUint32(lenValue).
    var len = O.length >>> 0;

    // 4. If IsCallable(callback) is false, throw a TypeError exception.
    // See: http://es5.github.com/#x9.11
    if (typeof callback !== 'function') {
      throw new TypeError(callback + ' is not a function');
    }

    // 5. If thisArg was supplied, let T be thisArg; else let T be undefined.
    if (arguments.length > 1) {
      T = thisArg;
    }

    // 6. Let A be a new array created as if by the expression new Array(len) 
    //    where Array is the standard built-in constructor with that name and 
    //    len is the value of len.
    A = new Array(len);

    // 7. Let k be 0
    k = 0;

    // 8. Repeat, while k < len
    while (k < len) {

      var kValue, mappedValue;

      // a. Let Pk be ToString(k).
      //   This is implicit for LHS operands of the in operator
      // b. Let kPresent be the result of calling the HasProperty internal 
      //    method of O with argument Pk.
      //   This step can be combined with c
      // c. If kPresent is true, then
      if (k in O) {

        // i. Let kValue be the result of calling the Get internal 
        //    method of O with argument Pk.
        kValue = O[k];

        // ii. Let mappedValue be the result of calling the Call internal 
        //     method of callback with T as the this value and argument 
        //     list containing kValue, k, and O.
        mappedValue = callback.call(T, kValue, k, O);

        // iii. Call the DefineOwnProperty internal method of A with arguments
        // Pk, Property Descriptor
        // { Value: mappedValue,
        //   Writable: true,
        //   Enumerable: true,
        //   Configurable: true },
        // and false.

        // In browsers that support Object.defineProperty, use the following:
        // Object.defineProperty(A, k, {
        //   value: mappedValue,
        //   writable: true,
        //   enumerable: true,
        //   configurable: true
        // });

        // For best browser support, use the following:
        A[k] = mappedValue;
      }
      // d. Increase k by 1.
      k++;
    }

    // 9. return A
    return A;
  };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) for JQuery map, specifically the part where it talks about the callback.

In JavaScript, a function can be called with any number of arguments, no matter how it was defined. So inside the definition of `jquery.map`, it calls the supplied callback n times where n is the number of elements in the array, and in each call passes two arguments, the first being an element of the array in Object form, the second being the index of the item in the array which is an Integer.

Your callback could technically have zero arguments if you just want to generate a new array of length n from a zero-argument function.

Answer (score 0):

```
var images = jQuery.map((1234567 + '').split(''), function(n) {
  return '<img src="' + n + '.png" />'
})
```

You have this piece of code: `(1234567 + '')`. It will convert the number to string. Then `split('')` will just split all digits in items of an array. The callback function is called for each item and n will get each value in array.
The nature of `$.map` is to save on top of the items from the original array whatever the callback will return.
In this case, you will have an array that looks like `["1","2","3","4","5","6","7"]`. After you run the map, you will get the images array

```
images=[
        '<img src="1.png" />',
        '<img src="2.png" />',
        '<img src="3.png" />',
        '<img src="4.png" />',
        '<img src="5.png" />',
        '<img src="6.png" />',
        '<img src="7.png" />'
    ]
```